# OpenSSL enabled but not working

Tags: php, apache, ssl, ftp, openssl

I am running Apache 2.2.13 and PHP 5.2.12. Just installed PHP 5.2.12 manually (to have access to all extensions) and enabled OpenSSL. phpinfo() indicates OpenSSL is enabled and running OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009.

I'm getting this error: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect().

I've seen where the PHP manual suggests 'ftp_ssl_connect() is only available if both the ftp module and the OpenSSL support is built statically into php' and further states that 'you must compile your own PHP binaries' to make it work with Windows.

I have the suspicion that phpinfo() only indicates OpenSSL as being 'enabled' because I have uncommented the line 'extension=php_openssl.dll' and have the correct dlls in the correct folders and the correct path in the environment variables. And perhaps a static build into PHP must be accomplished regardless of what phpinfo() indicates.

I believe the objective of distribution (as described above) is for dynamic extensions, but recompiling (for OpenSSL) is to encode a static extension.

ftp extension is working fine (built into PHP 5.2). I test this with the following code:

$conn_id = ftp_connect($url);
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password);
ftp_close($conn_id);

Note that to check ssl, I only change ftp_connect to ftp_ssl_connect. When reaching this line, I get the PHP error above in my Apache error log file.

Answer (score 4):

As the [documentation states](http://www.php.net/ftp_ssl_connect) *(quoting what you already quoted)* :

> Note: Why this function may not exist
>   
> `ftp_ssl_connect()` is only
>   available if both the ftp module and
>   the OpenSSL support is built
>   statically into php, this means that
>   on Windows this function will be
>   undefined in the official PHP builds.
>   
>  **To make this function available
>   on Windows you must compile your own
>   PHP binaries.**

You say you installed PHP "manually" ; but this probably still means you used an "official" build from php.net -- which means you have not compiled your own PHP binaries... So, that function is not available.

There is no magic : it seems you'll have to re-compile PHP, using the right configuration options at compile-time, if you want to be able to use that function...

Here's some documentation about that : [Build your own PHP on Windows](http://wiki.php.net/internals/windows/stepbystepbuild) -- but... good luck... i've never heard it was "simple" to compile PHP on windows, actually *(it's not that hard on Linux, but Linux is maybe a bit more well suited when it comes to compilation)*

A couple of other solutions :

- switching to Linux for your developments *(even if it's only using a Virtual Machine)* -- but you might still have to recompile PHP to get that *(might not be enabled by default)*
- just not using that function ; after all, do you know if your hosting service will provide you with it ? *(If you can't use it on your production server, no need to use on your development/testing machine)*

Comment: Yes, I only downloaded the build and did not compile the source.  I do need to check my host to see if they will provide it (I expect so, they are running FreeBSD).  My objective is to code automatic ftp backup securely.  I may continue to search for a more suitable solution.  Thanks.

Comment: I too ran into this problem and was able to work around having to compile the binaries by instead using a third party FTP program with scripting capabilities. You can set the files to backup, when they are backed up, and any security options you need. WS_FTP and WinSCP are some good, free options to look into that support SSL and scripting. Depending on what is required for your backup, basic tasks can be set through a GUI if you are more comfortable with that. If you happen to be stuck working with an environment you don't feel comfortable messing around with, this may be your best option.