# Symfony2 : Undefined Function "ftp_ssl_connect"

Tags: php, symfony, ssl, ftps

I want to connect my Symfony2 App with a FTPS :

```
$ftp = ftp_ssl_connect("ftps://remote.platform.pro", 990);
```

But I have this error :

`UndefinedFunctionException: Attempted to call function "ftp_ssl_connect"`

It seems that Symfony does not recognize this function, which seems crazy! 
Is there a service or other specific function to use instead?

__ My work environment __

- *Windows 7*
- *XAMPP 3.2.1*
- *PHP 5.5.6*
- *Symfony 2.4.2**

I found nothing in forums and documentation so any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: have you tried \ftp_ssl_connect() (with the \ )

Comment: No but I still have the same error. Exept that insteed `Attempted to call function "ftp_ssl_connect" from namespace` I got `...from GLOBAL namespace` :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you enabled OpenSSL ?

To do this, you have to open php.ini and remove the semicolon to:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Otherwise you probably find an answer here :

[Stack Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963834/openssl-enabled-but-not-working)

Comment: Yes OpenSSL was enabled. Indeed I should recompile PHP but it seems complicated on Windows. Easiest Solution found: I tried with Linux Ubuntu dual boot. It works perfectly! I think I'll definitely use Linux to develop. Thank you for the link: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963834/openssl-enabled-but-not-working).

Comment: Indeed, it is more convenient to develop on Linux :)