# MacPorts PHP 5.5 ftp_ssl_connect() not available

Tags: php, apache, ftp, openssl, macports

I want to use PHP's ftp_ssl_connect() on my Mac, but I'm getting an error message that the function is not available:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function ftp_ssl_connect()

I've installed Apache and PHP through MacPorts. I'm using PHP version 5.5.23. I've added FTP and OpenSSL support by running:

```
port install php55-ftp php55-openssl
```

I've already tried restarting Apache. In PHPInfo() it does say my install supports both FTP and OpenSSL, but still I'm getting the error message above when trying to use ftp_ssl_connect().

How can I enable this function on my machine?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963834/openssl-enabled-but-not-working.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that post, but that concerns Windows.

I'm not sure how to recompile (or just reconfigure?) PHP through my MacPorts installation.

Comment: The first part of the first sentence doesn't seem to be windows-specific, so this probably applies as well. To recompile PHP through MacPorts with OpenSSL built in, you'd have to edit the appropriate Portfile and add the necessary flags and dependencies. You can file a bug about this, but I doubt the maintainer will want this change. Might be faster to compile it on your own.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I guess I'm going to figure how to recompile it myself then.