# PHP 7.1 ftp_ssl_connect not defined even with ext-ftp and ext-openssl enabled on heroku

Tags: php, ssl, heroku, ftp, ftps

I recently tried to implement `ftp_ssl_connect` in one of my applications, and following the instructions on the [heroku dev center php support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#php-7-1) article, I ended up with something like this:

```
"require": {
    "php": "~7.1.0",
    "ext-ftp": "*",
    "ext-openssl": "*",
    ...
}
```

But when I ran the code on the server, the heroku instance said that `ftp_ssl_connect` was not defined. After researching, I found a similar answer [that says that PHP must be compiled manually for these two to work together and make this function available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1963850) but I do not believe that is necessarily the right way to solve this issue.

*edit 1: originally mistyped 'openssl' as 'oauth' in initial post*

Comment: I see `ext-oauth` but not `ext-openssl`. Are you sure it's enabled? What does `phpinfo()` say?

Comment: @Machavity I added the results of `composer show --platform` to the end of this [excerpt of my phpinfo](https://gist.github.com/EntranceJew/dccd592e8368825b87ef1b88ea1da69d), I had typoed `openssl` as `oauth` in my post but not in my composer.json.

I also noticed that adding those two extensions to the composer json did not impact `php -i` output or the heroku deploy output significantly.